# What happens when a copy of a shared pointer is created whose object contains a unique pointer?

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers, ownership-semantics

I have been messing about with SFML, figuring out how a simple 2D game could be built. I just noticed this behaviour and couldn't figure out what's going on. Sample code for what is confusing me:

```
struct Unique {};

class Shared {
public:
    Shared() {
        p = make_unique<Unique>();
    }
    unique_ptr<Unique> p;
};

void SharedCopyTest() {
    Shared foo;
    //Shared copy = foo;    // Error: function "Shared::Shared(const Shared &)" 
                            // (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced 
                            // -- it is a deleted function

    shared_ptr<Shared> sharedPtr = make_shared<Shared>();
    shared_ptr<Shared> ptrCopy = sharedPtr; // No error
}
```

At this point, `&sharedPtr->p == &ptrCopy->p`; but how is it possible,  if `p` is of type `unique_ptr<T>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semantics of `std::shared_ptr` is that no copies are made of the pointed-to object. Instead it's the `std::shared_ptr` object itself that is copied, and it increases the use-counter of the shared pointer.

That why it works, because you're not actually making a copy of the `Shared` object.

This can be easily verified by using the shared pointers [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get) function to get the "raw" pointer:

```
sharedPtr.get() == ptrCopy.get()
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! So, since the compiler will auto-delete copy-constructors and copy-assignment operators if a class contains `unique_ptr<T>` members, do I not have to bother with explicitly deleting those for any such classes that I construct? This is quite convenient!